# BeautifulSoup не парсит на сервере Heroku

Tags: python, telegram-bot, beautiful-soup

Делаю Telegram-бота, который должен парсить спортивные события. Есть вот такой запрос:

```py
today = str(datetime.today()).split()[0]
url = 'https://www.championat.com/stat/football/#' + today
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
[s.extract() for s in html('script')]
```

И локально, и на сервере Heroku всё хорошо работает. Далее я хочу взять несколько блоков с помощью BeautifulSoup:

```py
tournaments = html.findAll("div", {"class": "seo-results__tournament"})
matches = html.find("div", {"class": "seo-results"}).findAll("ul")
```

Локально всё отлично работает, но как я загружаю бота на Heroku, то `.find` всегда выдает результат `None`. Как это можно починить?

Comment: BeautifulSoup на сервер установили?

Comment: @Denisxyz Да, установил